# How to reference an output value within an iam policy as a principal using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

So I have an I am policy and i want to be able to reference my athena workgroup arn as part of the principals section in my policy.

Am not sure what the correct approach is for this. So far I have the following in my **outputs.tf**

```
output "workgroup_arn" {
  description = "arn of newly created Athena workgroup."
  value       = aws_athena_workgroup.athena_workgroup.arn
}
```

My IAM policy as as follows :

```
    statement {
     sid       = ""
     effect    = "Allow"
     resources = ["*"]

     actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt*",
      "kms:Decrypt*",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:Describe*",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [ARN OF WORKGROUP]
    }
  }
```

Essentially for `aws_athena_workgroup` I am setting up encryption_configuration using KMS. I realised an IAM policy is needed so am assuming the identifiers here will be the arn of the athena workgroup.

Comment: Are they different modules or the same? If different, please add that part of the code to the question as well.

Comment: Both files are in the same module which is called athena.  I have not yet called this module in my components section. I am using TF Scaffold for my terraform setup.@MarkoE

Comment: I don't know what TF Scaffold is, but in other words they are all in the same directory/same file?

Comment: What is the issue in using aws_athena_workgroup.athena_workgroup.arn for your reference in policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the elements (i.e., the IAM policy and the Athena workgroup) are in the same directory, there is no need to reference outputs, rather the attributes exported by the resource can be used (`aws_athena_workgroup`):

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "athena_workgroup" {
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Then, in the policy, you would just reference the ARN attribute like this:

```
    statement {
     sid       = ""
     effect    = "Allow"
     resources = ["*"]

     actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt*",
      "kms:Decrypt*",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:Describe*",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_athena_workgroup.athena_workgroup.arn]
    }
  }
```

Comment: So if the IAM policy was in a different directory , would that mean the output would be used then ?

Comment: No, that means that if you were to invoke a different set of modules and you would require an output from this module, then you would need to use a different syntax. Also, please take a look here if this answers your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.